# Inserting a single value into a column with a where clause

Tags: mysql, sql

Im trying to insert 'testing' into my MeetingNotes column under two conditions but for the life of me I cannot get it to work. Is it possible to do this? I am a beginner with sql and mysql? Thanks in advance!

```
SELECT MeetingNotes
FROM Meeting
INSERT INTO MeetingNotes
VALUES ('testing')
WHERE MeetingProcessId = '1001' AND MeetingId = '25'
```

Comment: Why would you insert one value with a where clause? I would understand if you were inserting from somewhere else, and you wanted to specify a where clause on the source, but here it makes no sense.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You want to use [an UPDATE query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/update.html), which changes values in existing records. [An INSERT query](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) strictly *adds new records*.

```
UPDATE Meeting
SET MeetingNotes = 'testing'
WHERE MeetingProcessId = '1001' AND MeetingId = '25'
```

For future reference, I'm not sure why you have a SELECT statement in your example: it isn't needed to insert or update records. Inserting a new record into the Meeting table (given only the three columns shown) would look like this:

```
INSERT INTO Meeting (MeetingId, MeetingProcessId, MeetingNotes)
VALUES ('25', '1001', 'Notes about this very exciting meeting...')
```

A couple notes on this:

- Since INSERT statements add an entirely new record to the table, columnwise constraints can't be applied, so they don't support a WHERE clause
- If `MeetingId` is an auto-incrementing record ID generated by the database, it should be / must be left out of INSERT statements
- Only string (CHAR/VARCHAR) values should be quoted when they appear in queries, numeric values should not. So if, for example, MeetingId and MeetingProcessId are integer instead of string columns, the quote-marks around `25` and `1001` in the queries above should be removed

Comment: Thank you I have a blank column and I automatically think insert. I knew it was something obvious I was missing. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is probably:

```
UPDATE Meeting SET MeetingNotes='testing' WHERE MeetingProcessID = '1001' AND MeetingId = '25';
```

Comment: Thanks you. I automatically think insert when there is a blank column. I have to get out of that habit. Thanks for taking the time to answer and help me out.

Comment: Welcome, you should accect Dan j's answer since it is much more complete and he answered a couple of seconds before me ^^